# How to Create a Custom Registration form and Approval Process in Magento?

Tags: magento

We are setting up a new Magento site and will allow clothing designers the ability to sell their products in our store.  We've already created a separate user group with appropriate permissions for Designers.  However, we need to create a custom registration form for use by them, and an accompanying approval workflow.  Can someone provide links to guidelines in creating such a custom form and workflow?  Is it advisable to create a separate store for each designer, or create user defined attributes to assign a designer to their products in the main store catalog?  Also, given that we will have a separate and changing commission percentage for each designer, what custom module logic must be used to apply these commissions correctly?  Specifically, what Magento objects must be leveraged to produce such a commission process?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 examples that should help:

- [Magento – Custom email contact form with notification system](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/)
- [Contact Form in Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/contact-form-in-magento/)